# Linear Mapping For Weight function

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$ be a basis of a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$ and let $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n$ be any $n$ elements of $V$. Define $T : V \to V$ by $$T(\alpha_1v_1 +\alpha_2v_2+ \ldots +\alpha_n v_n)=\alpha_1w_1 +\alpha_2w_2 +\ldots+\alpha_nw_n$$ for $\forall \alpha_i \in \Bbb F$.
Show that T is a linear function. Is T an isomorphism? Prove your answer.

To show it is a linear function I have to prove that $T(\alpha_1v_1)=\alpha_1T(v_1)$, which is trivial, or is it? And same with $T(\alpha_1v_1 +\alpha_2v_2)=\alpha_1w_1 +\alpha_2w_2=T(\alpha_1v_1)+T(\alpha_2v_2)$.

if it is an isomorphism I just have to show kernel is $0$ only. But I believe since this linear transformation the coefficients from F is not the same (if $a1=a1=\ldots$, then $w1=w1=\ldots=0$), then $0$ is not the only kernel element, thus not isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

To show it is linear take two elements $x,y$ of $V$ and show $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$ and also $T(\beta x)=\beta T(x)$ for any $\beta \in \mathbb{F}$.
So write (to apply the definition of $T$)

$$x=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i \text{ and } y = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha'_i v_i$$

for basic coefficients $\alpha_i, \alpha'_i \in \mathbb{F}, i=1,\ldots n$, etc.

It's not hard, but you have to be precise.

You're right that $T$ need not be an isomorphism. Claim: It will be one iff $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n\}$ also is a basis for $V$. You should  give a concrete example (in $\Bbb R^2$ will do) to see that this can be the case, or prove my claim in full detail.

Comment: can you give a basic counterexample? thanks

Comment: @jamesblack A very simple one: $V=\mathbb{R}$, $v_1=1$ is a basis, and taking $w_1=0$ gives a non-isomorphism.

Comment: @jamesblack Or $\mathbb{R}^2$ standard basis and $w_1= w_2$ any vector.

Comment: got it thank you

Comment: just out of curiosity, can you give a brief proof of the claim or do you have a link to a similar proof?

Comment: @jamesblack It's not hard from the definitions. Other stuff to do now.